# Zlib library image compression not working properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, zlib

I'm trying to compress an image using zlib library on python (vscode). I generate an output file but it weights the same as the original file.

This is the code:

```
import zlib

with open("garenap.jpg", "rb") as in_file:
    compressed = zlib.compress(in_file.read(), -1)

with open("arroz", "wb") as out_file:
   out_file.write(compressed)
```

Comment: JPEG is already a highly-compressed format.  If there was any practical way of compressing it further, *the JPEG format would be doing that already.*

Comment: My file is "jpg" format, not "JPEG"

Comment: `jpg` is a shorthand for `JPEG`. Same format.

Comment: I think you are right. When i tried compressing a "png file" it went from 188kb to 185kb, so it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1):

I think the two files would not weight the **exact** same. If you try the following:

```
import zlib

with open("garenap.jpg", "rb") as in_file:
    compressed = zlib.compress(in_file.read(), -1)
    print(in_file.tell())

with open("arroz", "wb") as out_file:
    out_file.write(compressed)
    print(out_file.tell())
```

you should see two slightly different numbers (which are basically the file size).

For some `jpg` of mine I got:

> 3563384
>
> 3448655

so the `zlib.compress()` is actually reducing the file size a tiny bit.
You should observe something similar yourself too.
Anything that is not the same number is fine.

As @jasonharper already pointed out, the [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) format is already highly compressed, but not [DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) compressed, as [`zlib`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) would do (including the implementation [available in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html)).
This is a bit different from the lossy compression implemented in JPEG, which is based on an [integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform). The output of this transform is typically non-redundant and therefore the [Lempel-Ziv 77 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) implemented with DEFLATE (or any other implementation, for what is worth) is of limited efficacy.

In conclusion, `zlib` is doing its job, but it is unlikely to be effective for `jpeg` data.

---

## Note on *larger* compressed files

The `zlib` compressed files can be larger than their inputs.

This is true for any loseless compression algorithm, and can be easily proved: consider multiple consecutive applications of a loseless algorithm, if any application would strictly reduce the file size, you would eventually get to a size equal to `0`, i.e. an empty file. Obviously this cannot be inverted, thus demonstrating that **loseless** compression is not compatible with **always** reducing file size.

Looking into LZ77 details from Wikipedia:

> LZ77 algorithms achieve compression by replacing repeated occurrences of data with references to a single copy of that data existing earlier in the uncompressed data stream.

The following is not exactly how LZ77 works but should give you the idea.
Let's replace repeating characters with the character followed by the number of times it is repeated.
This algorithm works well with `xxxxxxxx` being reduced to `x8` (`x` 8 times). If the sequence is non-redundant, e.g. `abcdefgh`, then this algorithm would produce `a1b1c1d1e1f1g1h1` which does not reduce the input size, but would actually *DOUBLE* it.
What you are observing is something similar.

Comment: The jpeg weights more after being compressed.